# gcc inline asm without instruction

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly

Is it "legal" to have a gcc inline asm statement without the actual instruction?

For example, is the asm statement "legal"? Will it introduce undefined behaviour?

```
int main(){
  int *p = something;
  asm("":"=m"(p));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you've provided an output, but the result is not used, the compiler (assuming gcc compatibility) is free to eliminate the asm expression.

Comment: It is ok, but what are you hoping to achieve? One common empty asm is asm("":"+m"(f)) to force rounding of a float f on x87.

Comment: Yes, it is still good.  As I said below, using extended asm can (possibly) introduce minor inefficiencies, but it will not result in incorrect code.  If it really makes you uncomfortable leaving this blank, you can always add a comment (`"# no code here today!"`).

Comment: But @ David,  the "=" modifier indicates the value of p is replaced by the inlined instruction (in this example, it should be erased since the instruction is empty) . Therefore, when we use *p in the future, it may cause a seg fault. Is my understanding right? (you may try this example with `return *p` on gcc-{other than 4.8} -O3).

Comment: p is not 'erased' by this code. In unoptimized code it will be 'something' before the asm, and unchanged afterwords. When optimizing, it may skip the assignment of p, since it can see that it is about to be overwritten (leaving it undefined), but if 'something' is a function, it may call it anyway, depending. But that's not due to the asm being blank. If the asm has code but fails to assign a value to p, you would have the same problem. If the asm is blank because you are removing some essential functionality, then yeah, changing it to blank could be an issue.

Comment: When optimized, why it will skip the initialization of p? I think it should behavior in the same way as the unoptimized version (leaving p unchanged). According to my understand of the answers, the asm statement  does not have side effects in this example. Is that correct?

Comment: Consider: `int x=5; x=6; x=7;`. Unoptimized, it will perform all 3 assignments. However, the optimizer can clearly see that x is never used when its value is 5 or 6, so it can skip straight to x=7. Similarly `int x = 9; asm("":"=r"(x));` can skip the assignment of 9 (leaving?). Perhaps using `+` will give you what you want? Other than what I mentioned below re flags, asm does not have side effects. But neither does it have effects (like 'erasing' the current value of outputs). I'm not sure how you plan to actually use this information, but I'm not sure it's going to give you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(){
 int *p = 0;
 asm("":"=m"(p));
 return 0;
}
```

Compiles without any errors, but it is unnecessary:

```
main:
.LFB0:
.cfi_startproc
pushq   %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.cfi_offset 6, -16
movq    %rsp, %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 6
movq    $0, -8(%rbp)
movl    $0, %eax
popq    %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
ret
```

GCC completely ignores that empty `asm` statement.

Answer (score 0):

In that specific example, the compiler can see that none of the outputs of the asm (ie `p`) are ever used.  Since the asm is not volatile (and has at least 1 output), the compiler is free to completely discard the statement during optimization.

It may also be worth mentioning that on i386, all extended asm statements (ie ones with parameters) always implicitly clobber fpsr (floating point flags) and eflags (think: `cc` clobber).  If the statement isn't completely discarded (for example if it is volatile), this *might* have an effect.  If it does, it will at worst be a **tiny** loss of efficiency, not incorrect results.

So to sum up:

- Yes it is legal.
- No it doesn't introduce undefined behavior EXCEPT that the value of `p` could be undefined since you are saying that you are overwriting the contents, but you aren't actually putting anything in it.
- It can, theoretically, introduce tiny inefficiencies, but it probably won't.